# zip archive not asking for password while unzipping but 7z file does, other files like 7z?

Tags: encryption, zip, 7-zip, password-protection, unzip

Zip password protected file is not asking password while opening, we can view internal file but this is not the same case with 7z file. while opening 7z file it asking  for password.I want to know what are the others archive file like 7z archive file which itself password protected. Please help in this . thanks in advance

Comment: You created a password protected *.zip file but when you unzip the file it doesn't ask for the password? How did you create that zip file? There is also a program called winrar to create compressed folders, it is not freeware but you can use it without activating it forever just with some ads...

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you _extracting_ or not? The ZIP central directory is not encrypted! Only file data.

Comment: [7z file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18nSlSMZGaYRra0FUSi7eqRagYCYx9WkT/view?usp=sharing)   [zip file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n281ZyaY0-QWct5NevxiGIdJeScuV2y7/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: my question is the two file i shared in above comment. if you try to open 7z file it will ask for password (u cant view internal file) . but in case of zip file you can view internal file while extraction only it will ask for password. want to know what is diff between these two file. what are the other archive file like 7z. i am new to archive extraction and encryption.

Comment: As @DanielB stated, the file directory of a standard ZIP file is not encrypted.  7z is a different format and does encrypt the file directory.